# Metal train got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_epochs'

Tags: python, machine-learning, metal

I am writing a Python code and in this part of the code, I want to use Metal to train my Model, like here:

```
from metal.label_model import LabelModel
gen_model = LabelModel()
%time gen_model.train(L_train[0], n_epochs=500, print_every=100)
```

But that gives:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

TypeError: train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_epochs'
```

Comment: Which version of `metal` you are using?

Comment: I am using  Version: 0.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 0.3.0 there's a change:

> 'Renames Classifier.train to Classifier.train_model to avoid
>   overwriting the nn.Module.train function'

So try using `train_model()` instead of `train()`:

```
from metal.label_model import LabelModel
gen_model = LabelModel()
%time gen_model.train_model(L_train[0], n_epochs=500, print_every=100)
```

Source:

https://github.com/HazyResearch/metal/commit/4210c7c66f3f4a6fc7287192aec133c293ed8198

Comment: glad it did :) if this (or any other answer ever :)) helped you, you can think of [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. cheers!